# Restringir acesso à Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma Web API onde restringi o acesso a seus métodos atráves do `EnableCors`, indicando a URL que quero dar permissão, da seguinte forma:

```
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://myapp.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetItem(int id) { ... }
}
```

Dessa forma, se tento acessar a minha *controller* de uma aplicação que não seja da url "http://myapp.net" o bloqueio acontece como esperado.

Porém, quando tento acessar a api direto, apenas colando e acessando no browser a url da minha minha api "www.minhaapi.com./GetItem/2", o bloqueio não acontece.

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de permitir o acesso a minha api apenas de um domínio x?

Comment: O que seria este "bloqueio" para evitar o copiar-e-colar? A meu ver, está tudo certo. É assim que o CORS se comporta.

Answer (score 2):

Opa. A política de mesma origem implementada pelos browsers, a grosso modo, é apenas uma forma de evitar requisições de um domínio para o outro (você carrega um site no domínio A que faz uma requisição assíncrona de algum recurso de um domínio B).

Mas essa proteção não impede você de acessar o recurso diretamente pelo navegador.

Então essas mudanças que você fez para permitir o cross origin (CORS) estão se comportando conforme esperado.

Agora, a título de exemplo, se você quer bloquear qualquer conexão que não seja  de uma faixa de IP, você pode pensar em regras de firewall ou negar acesso (rejeitar a request) conforme o ip do cliente na própria aplicação.